# Conditions on product of linear factors with positive coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Given real numbers $u_1,\dots,u_k$ such that the all the coefficients of the polynomial (including constant term)
$$
P(x) = (x+u_1)(x+u_2)\dots (x+u_k)
$$
are positive.

Can we conclude that $u_i \geq 0$ for all $i$?

If $k=2$, the answer is clearly yes. What happens in the general case is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, is it true that if a monic polynomial of degree $k$ with $k$ real roots has positive coefficients, then all its roots are smaller or equal than $0$?

The answer is of course "Yes", because if $\alpha>0$ then $P(\alpha)=\alpha^k+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a_j\alpha^j\ge \alpha^k>0$.

Comment: No. The question converse of that. We have make a conclusions about $u_i$ given the positivity of the polynomials.

Comment: Not the one I am reading right now.

Comment: I am not saying that it is given. I am saying that the $a_j$-s are positive.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.